# Appearing visible to selected contacts in Skype

Tags: skype, status

How can we appear visible to selected contacts while remaining invisible to others?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's been requested for years on the Skype community forums, or just outright shot down, but currently, this is not possible to do.

Your current options include:

- Creating an entirely new account and only adding in the contacts from your original that you wish to contact you whenever.
- Set yourself as "Do Not Disturb" and hope those you don't want to talk to won't talk to you while you're set at that status.

Or just stay invisible and continue messaging with a select few contacts only.

Comment: Thank you for the link. This is really annoying, I don't like too much the alternatives.

Comment: @random, It's been 5 years. Still no fix for this feature?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any selective status display, but as an invisible user you can still receive calls.  Your caller just won't know beforehand whether you're "on" or not.  When they attempt a call it will either ring or report "User is not online".
You could either let those few people know when you've signed on via Skype IM, or tell them you're staying invisible and to try anyway.  (Obviously this only works if you're willing to have that select group attempt to call anytime; if you're going to change by whom/when you want to be called when invisible, you'd need a true whitelist.)

Answer (score 2):

Block them temporary, by right clicking on the user > click Block this person.
you'll see as invisible and don't get messages.When you unblock, you can get messages all messages above(with block time messages)

Comment: Blocking is a poor option, especially since those contacts *can tell* you just blocked them.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows Skype:

1. Create a new group
2. Select all contacts in group
3. *Right-click* on selection and choose "block these people"

Comment: Blocking is a poor option, especially since those contacts *can tell* you just blocked them.

Comment: @Gabriel,  When you block someone they wouldn't be notified right?

Comment: @Pacerier no, but they can tell they are blocked because you disappear from their contacts list completely.