# Show different status to different contacts in Skype

Tags: skype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invisible for all in Skype but not for specified contacts](https://superuser.com/questions/156701/invisible-for-all-in-skype-but-not-for-specified-contacts)

In Skype, is it possible to be shown as "Online" to some users (e.g. the one I am calling) while to be shown as "Do Not Disturb" to others?

Comment: do you mean like blocking other users, as in right click, "block this person?"

Comment: No, I don't want to remove them from the contact list. I just want to show them (temporarily) a different status.

Comment: Similar to http://superuser.com/questions/156701/invisible-for-all-in-skype-but-not-for-specified-contacts. The consensus was: No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is currently not possible to do this in Skype, despite it being a heavily requested feature.